# How to send a request to a web api that changes an array in json that is always takin null value?

Tags: c#, json, xml, api, asp.net-web-api

I created a web API using ASP.NET, the API is already connected o a database and works fine, however I find a problem when I do a post of put request on one of my models, this model have an array inside, but every time I create a model, or try to modify it with a put request the array always is a null array; I am trying using postman just to make the request, all the properties change correctly with the put request except for the array values.

I tried using a post and put request using JSON and XML with postman, I researched a lot and can't find a solution

This is how the web api saves the data:

```
<Empleado xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/easy_date_WebAPI.Models">
    <Id>1</Id>
    <apellidos>Toro</apellidos>
    <email>alejo@gmail.com</email>
    <nombre>Alejandro</nombre>
    <telefono>123456</telefono>
    <horarios 
   xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" 
   i:nil="true"/>
</Empleado>
```

And i am doing the request this way:

```
{
    "horarios":["1","2"],
    "Id":1,
    "apellidos":"Toro", 
    "email":"a@gmail.com", 
    "nombre":"Alejandro",
    "telefono": "123456"

}
```

It should change the horarios values to the array I am sending, but it doesn't happen, and I don't receive any error message, just that horarios is null.

The model looks like this:

First i have a model persona:

```
public class Persona
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public string apellidos { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string telefono { get; set; }
}
```

Then i inherit persona in empleado:

```
public class Empleado : Persona
{

    public List<String> horarios { get; set; }

}
```

I also tried changing the list to a vector and created a constructor initializing the vector, but i get the same result, the PUT request never modify the array horarios, only the other atributes, the same thing happen with the POST request.

I looked in the azure SQL database and noticed that the table doesn't have the column horarios. I am new to ASP.NET and SQL databases so i donn't know what is wrong,maybe i can create the column on my own to allow the array to be saved?

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and capture the good results using postman.  The capture results with c# app.  Make the initial request in c# look exactly like the postman request.

Comment: Can you show us the actual model -- the c# classes -- rather than just the XML serialization of them?  E.g. from the XML it's clear that `horarios` is an array -- but not what kind of array.

Comment: @dbc sure i'll post the model with a few other stuff i tried

Comment: You tagged this as [tag:asp.net-web-api].  What version are you using?  Is there any chance it's not [tag:asp.net-mvc]?

Comment: @dbc I am not sure what version of asp.net i am using, i am going to check, but it is a asp.net api; i used a visual studio template for web api. I just added new information to the description. It result that i looked on the azure SQL database and it doesn't have horarios in the table, is a complete mystery for my why, because the table created the other fields ok; so clearly the problem is that the array is always null because is not being saved. I am new to web apis and SQL databases so i don't have a clear understanding on why the problems is ocurring or how to solve it